# CakePhp Cron Mailer - Howto BCC

Tags: cakephp

I have searched High and low. I am not very technical and really struggling with this. Cron mailer, has no details about CC and BCC. I have tried variations of code to add a hard coded BCC into an outgoing email. Someone suggested an array, couldn't get it to work. I am sure this is simple, but any help would be appreciated. Line that I cant get going is commented out.

CODE

---

```
        $this->EmailQueue->to = $booking['Guest']['email'];

        //$this->EmailQueue->bcc = 'james@domain.com';

            $this->EmailQueue->from = $email;
            $this->EmailQueue->headers = array(
                'booking_token' => $booking['Booking']['token'],
            );
            $this->EmailQueue->additionalParams = '-f ' . $bounce_options['bounce_email'];
            $this->EmailQueue->return = $bounce_options['bounce_email'];
            $this->EmailQueue->subject = $template['EmailTemplate']['subject'];
            $this->EmailQueue->template = 'mailman_invitation';
            $this->EmailQueue->sendAs = 'both';
            $this->EmailQueue->delivery = 'db';
            $this->set('body', $template['EmailTemplate']['html']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the BCC into the headers variable of your EmailQueue variable.

You have to modify your code to this

```
$this->EmailQueue->headers = array(
                'booking_token' => $booking['Booking']['token'],
                'bcc' => 'email@tobebcced.com'
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply 

Tried this without any luck. Did manage to get another email sent with the following code, just not BCC. Any ideas?
  

$this->EmailQueue->to = $booking['Guest']['email'].',james@domain.com';